# Opening Chromium browser opens karma-chromium

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, karma-runner, chromium

I have installed Chromium browser on my ubuntu 14.04. I have also used karma-chromium-launcher for running tests on one of my project.

Now from sometime, when I open Chromium browser, karma-chromium version opens by default with all the history deleted.

I have tried uninstalling and installing again but still facing the issue. Does anyone know what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remove the application data completely. The chromium data must be left after uninstalling which is being used after reinstalling.

This link might help you:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/937021/remove-all-data-and-settings-of-an-uninstalled-application